# Locate NetSuite Outlook integration plugin download link

Tags: plugins, outlook, netsuite

We recently installed the Outlook bundle in NetSuite, however the link to actually download the addon for Outlook never displays. Any idea how to get this to show up?

Answer (score 1):

The link should show up in the Settings portlet on your Home Screen.

[image]

Here are the direct links to the the download page and installer:

https://system.netsuite.com/app/external/xml/outlook/outlookv3download.nl

https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=429&c=3563537&h=7c09acb0c6ba5104ac0d&_xt=.bin

Comment: Hmm, that's what I was expecting, however the link never showed up despite the bundle being installed and settings filled in. Any idea what setting I may have missed to get that link to display on the home page portlet?

Comment: We attempted using these links after confirming we followed all setup steps correctly and still failed to see the downloads. Unfortunately still ran into an issue with .Net & VB Tools during install. Perhaps there is an issue with Win10?

Comment: We never did see that link show up, though we were able to download the extension with the links provided, however then failed to install correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You said:

> We attempted using these links after confirming we followed all setup steps correctly and still failed to see the downloads. Unfortunately still ran into an issue with .Net & VB Tools during install. Perhaps there is an issue with Win10?

Did Netsuite move your data center? If so then the link would be:

https://system.na?.netsuite.com/app/external/xml/outlook/outlookv3download.nl

Replace the ? with your regional data center number. Worked for me.

Comment: Even if netsuite did move our datacenter, system.netsuite.com will redirect to the proper na.X server as required assuming we are in North America.